# How to use service name in DataStax and not IP?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, cassandra, datastax, bitnami

Using the **Datastax C# Driver** I'm trying to connect to Cassandra which was deployed to Azure Kubernetes Services using a Bitnami helm chart.

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
   .AddContactPoint("127.0.0.0") // example IP
   .WithCredentials("cassie", "some-pass")
   .Build();
```

When trying this locally I use `kubectl port-forward`, but when I'm uploading my service to Kubernetes I want to use service name. Many applications shown to me by colleagues use just that. When I add the link that helm chart gives to me after I install it

> Cassandra can be accessed through the following URLs from within the cluster:
>
> - CQL: service-name.some-namespace.svc.cluster.local:9042

I'm unable to connect, I'm getting a **Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException** and I have to use an IP.

How to solve this problem. The IP changes every time I redeploy.
How can I use the name instead of the IP?

Comment: yes, you can use name instead of IPs - you just need to solve problem with DNS names

Comment: I'm kind of new to Kubernetes, what would you suggest to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, providing the DNS with format "DNS:PORT" as a parameter for AddContactPoint was not working. Using the method WithPort did the trick.

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
   .WithPort(PORT)
   .AddContactPoint("dns")
   .WithCredentials("cassie", "some-pass")
   .Build();
```